# If "God didn't play dice", would that imply superdeterminism?

Tags: metaphysics

Einstein had this famous "God doesn't play dice" because he don't like the inherent randomness appearing in quantum-mechanics.

If Einstein was right and nothing happens randomly, would that mean that there is superdeterminism?

Comment: If god doesn't play dice, then in what sense does it exist?

Comment: What is your question? To this day we dont know if there is randomness.

Comment: @YannikAmmann The question is in the title, and in the last sentence.

Comment: @Calmarius are you asking whether we live in a deterministic world, with the axiom that there is no randomness?? Because the answer would be `YES`... the definition of determinism is the absence of chance ... so I think I dont really understand your question.

Comment: Related question: http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/21510/any-argument-agains-determinism (I have an answer on that question that *directly* approaches the interpretations of QM and randomness)

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily so. There are determinist interpretations of quantum mechanics: bohmian mechanics, or the many world interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a comment, not an answer:

I'd be curious as what exactly Einstein intended by this phrase, and to what degree he actually believed and disbelieved in inherent randomness in Nature; simply because chance as a cause was affirmed in two theories of physics that have come down to us from Antiquity - Aristotles and Demicritus.

It seems strange to me that a Physicist of Einsteins calibre wouldn't be aware of this debate when he was aware of the debate around Machs Principle about the large scale structure of the universe determining inertial mass; and this is related to a rhetorical question of Aristotles, in his Physics, which asked how would we know we were in motion when space itself is homogenous.

Comment: It expressed his belief that quantum mechanics was incomplete -- the randomness of QM is due to some deeper theory.  That is part of why he was involved in formulating the EPR experiment.