# What is unique about the quantum state of superposition?

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-science, probability, quantum-interpretations

In the state of quantum superposition, as most famously illustrated by Schrodinger's Cat, we have a well-defined set of probabilistic outcomes that is not determined until observed. The cat is then said to "really" be in both states at once, while unobserved.

How does this differ from any other probability or what we might simply call "the future" or the "unknown." Isn't this simply a matter of introducing a time-bound "observer" into the picture?

From the naiveté of the question it should be clear that I'm hoping for some relatively simple distinction or epistemological assumption. Does it all hinge on the assumption of an "unobserved reality"?

Comment: It is a property of the Schrodinger wave equation that if you have two different solutions, then the sum of those two solutions is also a solution.  There are different interpretations of this property.  In the case of Schrodinger's cat, one solution is that the cat is alive, another is that the cat is dead, and therefore the sum of these two solutions - namely that the cat is both alive and dead - is another solution. This is one interpretation of the formalism. (Of course, Schrodinger's cat is to be taken in the spirit of a thought experiment.)

Comment: I should have added to my comment above that Schrodinger formulated his though experiment in order to illustrate the apparent absurdities of the theory.  A cat is not a quantum system.

Comment: Are you asking about how quantum superposition differs from ordinary classical probabilities which can be interpreted purely in terms of epistemic uncertainty about parts of the world we don't know about? For example if someone flips a coin and covers it with their hand, I may say that subjectively there's a 1/2 probability heads is facing up and and 1/2 probability tails is facing up, but I assume there's some definite truth about how the coin is oriented under the person's hand.

Comment: Yes, that is more or less what I am asking. But, as you suggest, I guess I am asking also about those "epistemic uncertainties."

Comment: How much familiarity do you have with the way classical probability works? Are you familiar with the idea of [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability), interpreting symbolic statements like P(A|B), and do you know about the [frequentist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequentist_probability) interpretation of probability, or should I explain these things if I reference them in an answer?

Comment: Once you have a "well-defined set of probabilistic outcomes", a.k.a. preferred basis, everything specifically quantum goes away, the Born rule reduces quantum prediction to a distribution on a classical probability space of those outcomes. You can then use your favorite interpretation of "uncertainty" on them, but it is the "observer" (measurement device, environment) that has to supply the preferred basis in the first place, the superposition itself is basis invariant. That the cat is "in both states at once" from pop-sci is just wrong, it confuses superpositions (sums) with conjunctions.

Comment: @Conifold - 'Once you have a "well-defined set of probabilistic outcomes", a.k.a. preferred basis, everything specifically quantum goes away' I wouldn't say *everything* specifically quantum goes away, for example in the electron double-slit experiment you can choose to measure in the position basis and you still have the fact that the probabilities the electron reaches different positions on the screen will be totally different depending on whether it is measured (or decohered) going through the slits, something that wouldn't be true for classical particles or waves.

Comment: Thanks all. Okay, guess I need to go back to the books. I have no training in this and haven't read any background in quite awhile, so my question as framed makes little sense. I know there are several interpretations of QM, from Copenhagen to Schrodinger to Wigner. I guess I was wondering if any compare it to ordinary probability or how "superposition" compares to any other case that has only probable outcomes, i.e. "the future," but lacking the math I think I'm mixing apples and oranges.

Comment: What about my question about whether you were familiar with the ideas of frequentism (that probabilities should be understood in terms of the statistics you'd see if you could do an infinite number of trials) and conditional probability (the probability that A occurred *given* that you know B occurred)? If you know about these, along with the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability#Example), it's possible to give a basic explanation of how a quantum experiment like the double-slit experiment doesn't match with what one would expect classically.

Comment: As a general note, this is a distressingly common pattern in philosophy: if you want to incorporate scientific conclusions, and you don't have a deep understanding of the science behind those conclusions, it is almost guaranteed that you'll misinterpret the results, and your argument will therefore be based on false premises. There's a whole lot of bunk swirling around that started when philosophers who didn't understand science tried to make arguments based on science.

Comment: @Nick already touched on this but Schrodinger's Cat is one of the most widely misunderstood thought experiments about quantum mechanics. Schrodinger's point was that the commonly accepted Copenhagen interpretation of QM was extremely lacking i.e. the idea of the cat being alive and dead at the same time is absurd and would never exist in reality. In a nutshell: 'the waveform collapses' is equivalent to 'then something happens'. This misconception has then become the basis for a lot of mystical thinking (e.g. 'The Secret') where human brains (but not cat brains) create reality.

Comment: Thanks, I do know the intent behind Schrodinger's paradox, I believe EPR had a similar intent, but ended up opening a can of worms. I think Von Neumann was responsible for the phrase "waveform collapse," but not sure. @probably. Not sure if the comment was addressed to the question itself, but personally I do not share the opinion that those without the math should forever hold their tongues. (These days, those with the math seem to jet off into plenty of fantasies all by themselves.) For the most part, I don't see that it does much harm, as long as you aren't an English prof.

Comment: @NelsonAlexander The problem is that philosophy doesn't exist in a vacuum. It can influence people. People who aren't in either science _or_ philosophy will often confuse the incorrect arguments of philosophers with the actual science. And this is where we get things like "quantum mysticism" and "quantum healing" that lead people to reject modern medicine in favor of snake oil, to the detriment of their health and in some cases even leading to their death.

Comment: @NelsonAlexander Anyway, out of curiosity, what specific things did you have in mind when you referred to the "fantasies" that "those with the math seem to jet off into"?

Comment: @probably. You may be stretching the definition and influence of "philosophers," though I have no dog in that fight. As we know, the "science wars" produced a lot of nonsense, but much interesting critique of the assumptions of science as well. Many "real" scientists these days, say Tegmark or Penrose, seem quite prepared to jump into metaphysical speculations, while Pauli was ready to embrace Jungian theories. The list could go on. My point is that the integrity of science is hardly subverted only by the uninformed speculations and intrusions of nonscientists.

Comment: @probably. I agree that for a society that depends on science, the general appreciation of such basic concepts as "falsifiability" it is dismal, possibly fatal. But I do not accept the proscriptions against using concepts from, say, Shannon information, in speculative or metaphorical ways, as long as the boundaries are clear . Oh, by mathematic "fantasies" I was simply referring to the criticisms of string theory or parallel universes, etc., that venture far beyond the reach of experiment. Nothing wrong there, but "knowing the math" is no perfect safeguard of scientific integrity.

Comment: @NelsonAlexander Tegmark and Penrose are physicists. They understand science (and, being theoretical physicists, also by necessity have a decent understanding of the philosophy of science) and are therefore decently well-equipped to make philosophical arguments based on science. This is not at all similar to the situation I'm talking about, which is, again, philosophers who _don't understand science_ making philosophical arguments based on science.

Comment: @NelsonAlexander As for Pauli, he represents an unfortunate example of someone who understands science generating "quantum woo" anyway. These examples appear to be much rarer, and don't constitute a trend in the same way that this happens in philosophy. The reason for this asymmetry is simple: most scientists aren't particularly interested in philosophy, beyond its immediate implications to their field. In contrast, philosophers are much more commonly interested in science, which is why that distressingly common trend exists.

Comment: @NelsonAlexander I never said that scientists didn't occasionally undermine their own field, just that they were much less likely to undermine their own field than non-scientists were to accidentally undermine science, by making arguments while not understanding it.

Comment: @NelsonAlexander The problem is that if you don't understand, for example, Shannon information, then you **don't know** what it means to demonstrate that "the boundaries are clear". Shannon's ideas are dependent on several foundational assumptions, and unknowingly violating those assumptions will lead you to conclusions that are simply wrong. You see this all the time with the concept of entropy - lots and lots of misleading ideas are founded on accidental misapplication or misinterpretation of statements about entropy.

Comment: @NelsonAlexander What specific criticisms of string theory make it a "mathematic fantasy"? It can't just be that it's far out of the reach of current experiment - after all, the prediction of the existence of gravitational waves couldn't be measured for an entire century, and yet we don't call general relativity a "mathematic fantasy". As for "parallel universes", it's difficult to tell what you're even talking about here - the many-worlds intepretation of quantum mechanics? The cosmological idea that the universe is part of a multiverse? Something other than that?

Comment: @NelsonAlexander There are valid criticisms of string theory, but they don't make it a "mathematic fantasy" any more than other theories being tested currently are. The criticisms I've seen are mostly about the large landscape of possible string theories, with many parameters that can take on large ranges - while this makes it difficult to guide experiments with predictions, this problem goes away with enough measurement. String theory is _not_ an example of a lack of scientific integrity.

Comment: @NelsonAlexander In fact, there are some predictions of string theory that are quite close to experimental tests. For example, AdS-CFT, a string-theory-based formulation connecting quantum field theory and gravity, predicts that the ratio of shear viscosity to entropy density in a material cannot get lower than a certain minimum value. Heavy-ion collisions at the LHC and RHIC are currently testing this limit, as the quark-gluon plasma generated in these collisions is currently measured to be very near the minimum value, though with wide margins of uncertainty.

Comment: Well, I hardly know what we are arguing about here. I certainly have a deep appreciation of "scientific method," not there there is total agreement on what that is, and I agree that in some sense you don't "know the science" without a proper background and so shouldn't appeal to its authority to sell quantum-engineered skin lotion and such. But I think you mischaracterize "philosophers," not that I am one. And science too does not "exist in a vacuum." Many scientific ideas from the time of Newton engender popular metaphors and concepts that may, in fact, be fruitful in other fields.

Comment: *"I do not share the opinion that those without the math should forever hold their tongues"* The math *is* the theory. If you don't understand the math, you don't understand quantum mechanics. But those who don't understand the math needn't hold their tongues; rather, they should *learn* enough of the math that they can speak about the subject intelligently.

Answer (score 20):

I recently answered a similar question on physics.SE [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/566641/50583). What is special about the probabilities of quantum mechanics is that the randomness cannot be explained by a theory of nature that is both local and realist, while classical probabilities can. Quoting myself:

> A "local hidden variable" theory is basically the classical idea of how the world works - everything has a list of well-defined properties, like position or momentum, and there is a "true" precise value for each of these at each time, and the laws of physics in principle determine the precise value at each other time from those at one instant. "Randomness" in this classical world is incidental, arising from incomplete knowledge, imperfect measurement devices, etc. When you flip a classical coin in the exact same way, it will always yield the same result. The "randomness" is just because humans are extremely bad at the level of consistency required to flip it "in the same way" again. The belief that there is a definite value for each property at all times is also called realism.

The other ingredient for a local hidden variable theory is *locality*, the idea that things that happen at one point cannot instantaneously affect the state of the world elsewhere, but that changes have to propagate at finite speed (lower than or equal to the speed of light, if you know about relativity, but that specificity isn't really necessary here).

[Bell's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_theorem) now says that quantum mechanics is incompatible with local hidden variable theories. No such theory can ever predict the results that we do, in fact, observe. So the probabilities of quantum mechanics are different from those of classical physics because they cannot be explained by a theory that is both local and realist. Interestingly, the standard technical formulation of quantum mechanics is neither really non-local nor really non-realist, but has more or less successfully delegated the decision about which of these traits we give up into a new realm of metaphysics called [quantum interpretations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretations_of_quantum_mechanics).

Beware of anyone trying to tell you that quantum mechanics implies a particular ontological claim about the world, e.g. the existence of "parallel universes", a peculiar power of "conscious observers" or the existence of "pilot waves". All these are interpretations, but all that Bell's theorem says is that no local and realist interpretation can be valid for quantum behaviour. It does not select one of these interpretations over the other, and the reason I've called these interpretations *metaphysics* above is that they usually make no different claims about the results of experiments - pure physics cannot distinguish them, or they are careful to make different predictions from "standard" QM only in areas where experiments are as of yet infeasible.

Comment: This seems to be the only answer that actually has the key point in it.

Comment: The proof of Bell's theorem has a loophole in that it assumes that for every measurement, there is a unique outcome. If you include this in the definition of "realism" then it's true that QM is incompatible with local realism, but if on the other hand you say a theory can still be "local realist" if it involves systems at different locations splitting into multiple local copies, then Bell's theorem no longer rules out locality. The MWI has been argued to be local in this sense, see the discussion of the arguments of Deutsch and Rubin [here](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qm-manyworlds/#7).

Comment: @Hypnosifl Yes, if I define realism differently from the standard definition exactly such that the MWI is realist, then Bell's theorem does not exclude local "realist" theories anymore, but that's a tautology. As I say, the notion of realism used here is essentially *"The belief that there is a definite value for each property at all times"* - if you have multiple local copies with distinct values, then there is no "definite value", and your theory is not realist by this measure. We can always redefine words to mean different things, what's your point?

Comment: As far as I know there is no standard technical definition of "realism" that addresses this issue, I have only ever seen it defined in somewhat vague verbal terms which might be read as compatible with the MWI (which does give an objective picture of reality independent of any particular observer's knowledge). Because of this vagueness, some prominent physicists like [Gilles Brassard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilles_Brassard) have argued that the MWI should be seen as "local realist", see [here](https://www.mdpi.com/1099-4300/21/1/87/htm)

Comment: Great answer :-) I would like to add, that the actual weirdness of quantum mechanics is not so much the concept of superposition, but rather the concept of entanglement. The fact that performing a measurement on a particle can instantly influence an entangled particle many light years away. Superposition is a prerequisite for entanglement, but it's the entanglement that really sets quantum theory apart. The Bell theorem formalizes this "spooky action at a distance" so far that it can be tested, and the tests say: "Yes, this spooky action exists. Screw locality or realism, you don't get both."

Comment: Bravo! More contributions on this side, please.

Comment: One of the best answers I have ever read in this SE in terms of clarity - Feynman would have been proud of you! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The "classical" form of quantum mechanics (no hidden variables or "pilot waves") maintains that a *state* exists as a superposition of all possibilities until the act of measuring that state causes the associated *wavefunction* to collapse. The collapse of the wavefunction then follows the probabilities for each possible state (for example, 40% spin-up and 60% spin down for a certain particle, etc.). And only when that measurement is repeated many, many times does the 40/60 split become apparent.

In Shrodinger's thought experiment, the possible states are "cat alive" and "cat dead" and he maintained that the wavefunction does not collapse until you open the box and measure the state of the cat. (By the way, this was intended as an illustration of a particle physics effect and not as a statement about how cats get poisoned. In reality, such effects are vanishingly small for all macroscopic objects like cats, which consist of billions upon billions of individual particles.)

This business hinges on the fundamental idea that (only!) in the world of particle physics, the trajectory of a particle into its future cannot in principle be known until measurements are made on it in its present. If this essential fact is omitted from the mathematical formalism used by quantum physicists to solve problems like this, you get the wrong answers when predicting the outcome of an experiment.

You can think of this as illustrating the difference between the *unknown* and the *undefined*.

Comment: "such effects are vanishingly small for all macroscopic objects like cats, which consist of billions upon billions of individual particles" What does # of particles have to do with it? The real problem with macro objects like cats is environmental decoherence, but if it's possible to isolate a large system sufficiently from its environment (easier for systems near absolute zero) it can evolve into a superposition of macroscopically distinct states (like the live and dead cat) according to QM, and see http://archive.is/ylWb for an example

Comment: Thanks, sounds clear but I will have to chew on it a bit, being unfamiliar with the technical underpinnings. It seems the distinction is more in the technical anomalies of QM compared to classical mechanics than in the way we think of probabilities generally, though these too seem to harbor weird paradoxes.

Comment: Much of what passes for startling new discoveries in physics, over time and with reflection turns out to be merely common sense recognitions of the interactions of bodies in space. Newtons description of the measurement of gravity, instead of being claimed as a 'Law', would have been better served as a 'recognizable process of magnetic attraction and repulsion due to the molten cores and masses of globular objects locked into a repeatable pattern of circumlocution around a massive star'. It's really just a common sense observation once the nature of objects in a  solar system are understood.

Comment: @CharlesMSaunders - Are you using "magnetic" metaphorically? The gravitational force is different from magnetic attraction (and there is no repulsive aspect to gravity, unlike with magnetism). It doesn't seem particularly common sense that there's an attractive force between two arbitrary masses regardless of composition since the attraction between human-scale objects is too minute to affect everyday life, and common sense also doesn't suggest why gravity should obey an inverse square law as opposed to some other mathematical function.

Comment: The same can be said for Einstein's theory of relativity; once escaping the mutual magnetic attractions and repulsions within a given solar system, it becomes simple scientific common sense to recognize that the potency of: gravity, time and energy will begin to dissolve and to wrap and warp around one another. It is not a 'Law' but another common sense regularity. Apply this process to QM and reflect on the interactions among nano-particles it is not so amazing or difficult to account for their interactions without making outrageously occult claims about how their actions disrupt physics.

Comment: They are not arbitrary masses but exist within a completely 'locked-in' revolution which keeps their trajectories completely predictable. Pause, don't worry about the terms magnetic and repulsion, it's simply that the effects of gravity do not cause anything. Gravity just explains that the solar system contains a measurably reasonable explanation for its stability.

Comment: @Hypnosifl, a cat is a system consisting of a large numbers of particles far above absolute zero so its decoherence will be strongly favored and its decoherence time will be correspondingly small. I think this is a suitable answer to the OP's question on a philosophy site, but I encourage you to post your own more detailed answer and I'll delete mine.

Comment: @CharlesMSaunders Which repulsions are there in a solar system?

Comment: @253751- Attraction and repulsion is simply a conversion of the mathematical inverse square into a conceptual frame. The point behind the two analogies presented were to suggest that we humans have a tendency to hyper-inflate the significance of what is 'new' knowledge to us and immediately to announce them as 'laws' of nature and upheavals to our established store of knowledge. Invariably we find ourselves at some later date finding it difficult to reconcile why something which never did have universal application into a law, as is the case with Newton's 'Laws', was regarded as one. regards

Comment: @CharlesMSaunders, I'm sorry but as a physics guy I don't know what your are trying to get across. can you express this mathematically for me?

Comment: @CharlesMSaunders As another physics guy, I also have no idea what you're trying to say, and in fact, I suspect most of it is based on a misunderstanding of what physics actually says. See my comment on the question: you're a prime example of the trend I'm talking about.

Comment: @probably_someone- Dear ..., since you are merely 'probably someone' and not 'actually someone', there is no need for me to take offense at your hurled insult. But just imagine my distress at how little someone sometimes, demonstrates any grasp of the analogy, imagination, modeling and imaginational supposition which adheres to all discussion of such non-existent particles as those referenced in QM. All the Best,

Comment: @probably_someone, I get the impression we are wasting our time over here. Better head back the the physics SE!

Answer (score 5):

The key characteristic of a quantum superposition is that all superposed states are equally real (or potentially real) at the physical level. This is quite different from a classical probability, which assumes that one state is real and the probability reflects our ignorance of the true state of affairs. That, basically, is it.

We know this to be true because quantum entanglement, via Bell's Theorem, allows us to compare the probabilities predicted by quantum theory with those predicted by classical statistics. This experiment has been carried out many times and classical statistics always gives the wrong answer: superpositions really are inherent in reality and not due to ignorance.

What follows is just a bit of background comment.

Different "interpretations" of the quantum equations express different opinions about the nature of the reality - actual, potential or merely likely - of the various superposed states.

Schroedinger is often assumed to have been claiming that his cat was both alive and dead at the same time. In fact he was doing the reverse, he was highlighting the ludicrous consequences of the idea that superposed states were in any way real. Out of this controversy arose the standard "Copenhagen interpretation", that there is no objectively meaningful reality to the superposed states; enquiry is futile and the good physicist should just "shut up and calculate".

Many other speculative interpretations have been developed - hidden variables, pilot waves, parallel universes where every state has a home, and so on, but they are all either falsified in the lab (most hidden-variable theories predict classical results for entanglement experiments) or untestable metaphysics (which Schroedinger lampooned with his cat).

Comment: What does it mean exactly to say they are all "equally real"? There are for example hidden variables interpretations where there would be some definite truth about the positions of a system of unmeasured particles even though QM would treat as being in a superposition of different position states--it's true these interpretations involve untestable metaphysics, but depending on what you mean by "equally real" (and whether it's taken as conflicting with these interpretations), your statement might involve untestable metaphysics as well.

Comment: @Hypnosifl I wrote, "equally real (or potentially real)", you should be asking what that means. Hidden-variable theories are cooked up to allow "proper" physical particles. Sophisticated variations on the two-slit experiment have passed the spin of an electron down one path and its momentum down the other, recombining them at the end. No particle-based model can explain that! The mainstream interpretation insists that the operative part of "equally real (or potentially real)" is the "equally" bit, the rest is a scientifically meaningless placeholder for your choice of metaphysics.

Comment: OK, what does it mean? I agree hidden variable theories seem "cooked up" and don't favor them myself, but either accepting them *or rejecting them* require untestable metaphysical assumptions, so if your comments about the "reality" of multiple paths are rejecting the assumption of hidden variables theories that say the particle has a single definite path it actually takes, then you are making such assumptions. As for the specific example you mention, it's been proven that Bohmian mechanics is identical to non-relativistic QM in *all* possible predictions, presumably including that experiment.

Comment: @Hypnosifl: The problem with hidden variables is not merely that they require untestable assumptions. The problem is that one of those assumptions must be either superliminal propagation of information (which is incompatible with general relativity) or superdeterminism (which is incompatible with methodological naturalism).

Comment: @Kevin - There is no conflict between relativity as a scientific theory and the *purely metaphysical* hypothesis of a "hidden" preferred definition of simultaneity that can't be determined experimentally, not even in principle, and "hidden" superluminal influences between quantum hidden variables which travel faster than light but never backwards in time with respect to this definition of simultaneity. Again, I don't favor such a view myself, but any arguments for or against this view also involve metaphysical claims rather than purely scientific ones.

Comment: @Hypnosifl: You can't have a hidden notion of simultaneity, because you can perform two simultaneous Bell experiments, and force the information to propagate in both directions at once. The only way to make this work is to rip up the entire theoretical model of relativity.

Comment: @Kevin - You'll need to provide more detail on your proposed experiment, I don't know what you mean by "two simultaneous Bell experiment" (how do you know they are simultaneous if the truth about simultaneity is hidden?) or what it would mean to "force the information to propagate in both directions at once" (what are the directions you're referring to?) If it would require time to explain you might consider starting a new question here or in physics.se, something like "does this experiment show it's impossible to have a hidden-variables model with hidden simultaneity"?

Comment: @Hypnosifl: You're the one claiming we can have hidden simultaneity in the first place, and I've not seen a thorough, worked example of that, so I'm simply going to discontinue the discussion.

Comment: @Kevin - It's trivial that you can have some form of metaphysical truth about simultaneity that doesn't conflict with relativity (simply pick some foliation of a relativistic spacetime into simultaneity surfaces, and declare this definition of simultaneity to be "metaphysically true" and all others "metaphysically false" with no changes to testable predictions). But you seemed to claim there was some specific thought-experiment that showed a problem with a hidden definition of simultaneity in connection with a hidden variables interp. of QM, I take it you don't have such a specific argument?

Comment: One might pick and "absolute" reference frame in rather the same arbitrary way that in projective geometry one may pick and "absolute" plane which mimics infinity. But, unlike the plane at infinity familiar to all perspective artists, the Relativistic choice has no physical relevance. Simultaneity within a metaphysical context has no physical meaning, it is quite different from localised simultaneity at a physical level and is a red herring, of no relevance whatsoever to any physical phenomena.

Comment: @Hypnosifl: The problem with your argument is that we need information to propagate in a spacelike fashion. In your privileged reference frame, that will look like information propagating faster than light, but in another reference frame, it looks like information propagating backwards in time. So now we can construct a tachyonic antitelephone in that other reference frame, which is *still* a tachyonic antitelephone in your privileged reference frame, because timelike relationships are preserved across reference frames.

Comment: @Kevin - You can't use it to construct a tachyonic antitelephone if the information only propagates in a way that makes it impossible to manipulate those signals to pass messages to a distant partner (say, by your choice of what spin axis to measure on entangled particles). If you look at my analogy for Bell inequality violations involving magic scratch lotto cards [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/140883/59406), you can see that even in the "violation of locality" scenario where the cards exchange signals FTL, I can't pass a message to a partner by choice of what box I scratch.

Comment: @Hypnosifl: If you cannot construct a tachyonic antitelephone, then either you do not actually have superliminal propagation of (classical) information, or you do not follow relativity. When we claim that "information" in the classical sense has propagated from event A to event B, we implicitly claim that an agent can measure that information. If it's not measurable, then it's not "information." The ability to measure is an essential property of information.

Comment: @Kevin - Something can be "information" from the point of an imaginary godlike observer who can see any part of the full objective state of the world including hidden variables, even if it is not measurable by *us*. Again see the "violation of locality" section of my physics.se answer I linked above, where I explicitly stipulated that from the objective point of view the two lotto cards are exchanging information FTL in order to coordinate their hidden variables, but the experimenters who can only select a single square on the card to uncover cannot use their choices to communicate messages.

Comment: ...more generally, any time it is the case that A and B are objective facts about the world and P(A|B) is different than P(A), this means that B provides information about whether A occurred, even if A and B are facts about hidden variables that aren't measurable by human experimenters.

Answer (score 3):

This is essentially the same as ACuriousMind's answer but a little more practical, which I find helps in considering philosophy.

The key difference is that quantum mechanics includes, more or less, *negative* probabilities, such that you can superimpose situations that both allow for some phenomenon *P* and this combination disallows *P*. To [quote Scott Aaronson](https://www.scottaaronson.com/democritus/lec9.html),

> Quantum mechanics is what you would inevitably come up with if you started from probability theory, and then said, let’s try to generalize it so that the numbers we used to call “probabilities” can be negative numbers. As such, the theory could have been invented by mathematicians in the 19<sup>th</sup> century without any input from experiment. It wasn’t, but it could have been.

As ACuriousMind has noted, when this happens you lose the ability to describe reality in a locally realist way, because if I locally change a + sign to a – sign, that can introduce correlations which no locally realist theory can explain. And it is worth you having an example in your mind. This example, I call “The Game of Betrayal.”

## The rules of the game

The idea of this is that it is a *coöperative game* for a team of three players. If you are not familiar with coöperative games, the idea is that the players all win or lose together and are trying to defeat the rules of the game—some such games include *Shadows over Camelot*, *Arkham Horror*, *Pandemic*, *Forbidden Island*, and the first half of *Betrayal at House on the Hill*. The team tries to work together and The Game of Betrayal tries to set conditions where they have to work at cross purposes.

To that end, the game relativistically separates the players so that no known physical phenomenon can be used to communicate between them. Each player is in a room with a screen, a timer, and two buttons labeled 0 and 1. When the round starts, a goal will be flashed on the screen and the timer will start to tick down, and before the timer hits zero the player must press exactly one of the two buttons, which will be transmitted to a central location. Once the three button presses are logged, the sum of the three pressed numbers will be compared to the transmitted goals, and we’ll figure out whether the team collectively won the round. Hopefully that description is clear enough of the physical situation the players find themselves in.

One fourth of the time, we run a *control round*. In this round we ask everybody *Make the sum of your numbers even* and the team will win if it is, indeed, even—or will lose if the sum of their three chosen numbers is odd.

Otherwise we choose one of the three at random, who we will call here the “traitor” (but we will never tell them that, they will not find out until the round is over). To the traitor, we broadcast the identical message, *Make the sum of your numbers even* and we are lying to him/her. To the other two, we broadcast the true goal: *Make the sum of your numbers odd*. And the team will win if the number is odd, or will lose if the sum of their three chosen numbers is even. (You can flip the goals if you want to, have the control rounds be “odd” and the traitor rounds be “even”, that makes no substantial difference.)

## Analysis

There exists no three-person strategy in classical probability which beats this game more than 75% of the time. The easy way to see this is, classical probability allows you to construct the exact same situation by asking both questions of each individual person and then you choose randomly which sort of round it was afterwards. Either way you can describe any such strategy as a joint probability distribution over six random variables: say our people are Alice, Bob, and Carol, then the six variables are *A*<sub>odd</sub>, *A*<sub>even</sub>, *B*<sub>odd</sub>, *B*<sub>even</sub>, *C*<sub>odd</sub>, and *C*<sub>even</sub>, and the four constraints we are placing upon this,

> *A*<sub>odd</sub> + *B*<sub>odd</sub> + *C*<sub>even</sub> ≡ 1 (mod 2),
> *A*<sub>odd</sub> + *B*<sub>even</sub> + *C*<sub>odd</sub> ≡ 1 (mod 2),
> *A*<sub>even</sub> + *B*<sub>odd</sub> + *C*<sub>odd</sub> ≡ 1 (mod 2), and
> *A*<sub>even</sub> + *B*<sub>even</sub> + *C*<sub>even</sub> ≡ 0 (mod 2),

suffice to construct an impossible equation «2 *x* ≡ 1 (mod 2)» and therefore classically, you must choose at least one of these constraints to violate.

Quantum players—players sharing an entangled quantum state over three qubits—can win each round 100% of the time, in theory. (In practice quantum states lose “coherence” as they interact with their environments and so even with very nice systems we might want to give some possibility of error, say 5%.) With enough rounds we can draw a clear distinction between these both and then issue a large cash prize and a small fee, to entice teams to build quantum computers and endure relativistic separation for several rounds and play this game. So for example if we require people to pass 38 out of 40 rounds, that accommodates a 5% error rate for the quantum players but if you can only pass each round with 75% probability then you only pass 38 out of 40 rounds something like 0.1% of the time.

The description of the simplest quantum strategy involves the single-qubit states |+> = √½ |0> + √½ |1> and |–> = |+> = √½ |0> — √½ |1>. By the normal rules of quantum mechanics the superposition

> √½ |+++> + √½ |———> = ½ |000> + ½ |011> + ½ |101> + ½ |110>

only involves states which make the sum of the bits even, so measuring this “GHZ state” in the computational basis will be sufficient to pass control rounds.

What about in the traitor rounds? Well, if any two individuals perform the unitary transformation which takes

> |+> ⇒ |+>,
> |–> ⇒ *i* |–>

where «*i* = √(-1)», then the overall state must flip sign to the state

> √½ |+++> – √½ |———> = ½ |001> + ½ |010> + ½ |100> + ½ |111>

at which point the sum of the three numbers is odd. So any one person unilaterally can change whether the sum will be even or odd, and two people can distribute this decision halfway between each other with no real problems.

## Some properties to note

I want to observe some particulars about the quantum strategy that tend to be relatively common properties.

(1) Quantum mechanics generally does not allow things that are individually completely *absurd* to happen. If you had instead set the goal for the control case as “make all of your numbers zero” then I would not have the quantum freedom to generate the 100% solution. It is precisely because both 0 and 1 are plausible answers in all cases, that individuals have the freedom to tweak the phases of those numbers and cancel out some probabilities.

(2) Nobody can determine that something remarkable has happened until all of the bits are collected back together. This allows quantum mechanics to still obey the constraints of relativity in practice, no “information” can be sent faster-than-light even though local theories fail to describe what is happening.

(3) Even then, it takes many trials to reveal the remarkable thing, as clear from (1). So a locally realist theory must allow *some* probability of random success on the correlation: and then a quantum theory, expanding on this, generates a strangely higher-than-expected success rate.

(4) This example is carefully chosen to make the success rate 100% but often quantum mechanics pushes back on you. Quantum mechanics does not always allow 100% success rates on every possible experiment; the algebra is actually somewhat constrained. So this is the subject of a “Bell’s inequality,” named for John Stewart Bell’s analysis of the Einstein-Podolsky-Rosen paradox, and in the original analysis the correlation of quantum theory is not 100% for the maximal violation where you put the one axis at 45° relative to the other axis.

(5) The quantum system could be analyzed by the approach given for the classical system, but this would correspond to a different fundamental experiment. If we tried to ask every quantum player for two bits (one for each response to the two questions) and reassembled their chance of winning after the fact, we would still construct that impossible equation which proves at least a 25% failure rate. The spooky correlation really requires us to ask four bits out of each player corresponding to each of the four round types. So we would say that “the choice of what to measure is influencing the outcomes” but while that is a valid way of looking at it, perhaps a better statement would say that classical probability is somehow recursively embeddable in a way that quantum probability is not, so that things which look like they are valid alternate approaches classically are invalid quantumly.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed offering, a bit above my innumerate skill sets, but I can chew on it slowly, and it does have a lot of interesting aspects, with the focus on probability itself, which was my interest, not the kitty.

Answer (score 2):

One important aspect of Quantum Mechanics that frequently gets lost in discussions avoiding the mathematics is that **there is no *absolute* distinction between "pure" and "superposed" states** — it is all so to say in the eye of the beholder, and that beholder is typically not some human experimenter but rather a physical observable (technically: self-adjoint operator on the quantum state). @GuyInchbald hints at this in his answer by pointing out that designating some states as pure is the same thing as choosing a basis for the space of quantum states, but I fear the point needs to be stressed much stronger when raised in a philosophical context.

## The case of spin

A system providing a good example of this arbitrariness of what to label as "pure" is that of the spin of an electron. The coarse popular science description is that the electron has the spin states 'up' and 'down', mathematically denoted +1/2 and −1/2 (for technical reasons that make sense in calculations). The slightly more refined description, which one encounters when wishing to discuss quantum superposition, is that the electron can also be in arbitrary superpositions of these states. After this comes the more seldomly seen (but really illuminating) further refinement that *spin is really tied to a direction in physical space* – we speak about 'spin up' and 'spin down' because there is a convention to use the eigenstates for spin in the Z direction as the standard basis when describing spin, but one could just as well use any other direction to define the basis states (those designated as "pure").

What is nice about the spin is that it is quite straightforward to observe, as is done in the [Stern–Gerlach experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Gerlach_experiment): when an electron travels through a suitable nonhomogeneous magnetic field (ideally constant in time and direction, but strength varying between different points in space), its path will be slightly diverted according to the direction of its spin, very much as classically a rotating charged particle would be (hence the name 'spin'). Practically the experiment is conducted with a beam of electrons: passing through the magnetic field splits the beam according to the spins of the individual electrons, and that is what in the more abstract discussion of QM is described as making a *measurement* of their spins. (IMHO there are problems with the way that the 'measurement' concept is used in discussions of QM, but more on that later.)

From the classical physics point of view, the outcome of the Stern–Gerlach is weird, because the beam is always split into *two* subbeams: each electron is either shifted a certain distance in one direction, or an equal distance in the opposite direction, corresponding to spins of +1/2 and −1/2 respectively. For a classical rotating charge the distance would depend on the speed of rotation, so an initial interpretation could be that all electrons seem to always rotate at the exact same speed, but it's actually a lot weirder, because the classical effect would also depend on how well the axis of rotation aligns with the direction of the magnetic field; getting two distinct beams out would classically only happen if all charges rotate at the same speed *and* all have axes of rotation parallel to the magnetic field. In the Stern–Gerlach experiment you get two beams no matter what direction the magnetic field has, so it seems like electrons have an axis of rotation parallel to every direction there is! But that was just because we were trying to make a strained classical interpretation; the modern consensus is that electrons aren't rotating as such, they just happen to have a property known as spin which (among other things) causes them to interact with magnetic fields in a way that resembles how rotating charged particles would interact. That spin is quantised is in itself no weirder than that electrons "orbiting" a nucleus only has a discrete set of possible orbits; we may gladly think of 'up' and 'down' as the two possible values of the physical quantity 'spin'. As long as we only measure spin in the Z direction.

Things get weirder if we repeat the experiment with one of the subbeams coming out of the Stern–Gerlach apparatus, for example that of 'up' electrons. Feeding that through another Stern–Gerlach apparatus with magnetic field in Z direction will *not* split the beam, because these electrons are all in the same spin state, and are thus shifted the exact same amount. Feeding the beam through another Stern–Gerlach apparatus with magnetic field in Y direction *will* however split the beam 50/50 into two subbeams, because even though measuring the spin of any particular electron always produces a value of either +1/2 or −1/2, measuring the spin in the Y direction is something different than measuring it in the Z direction; one does not determine the other. Yet the actual spin state of the electron is always just a superposition of two basis states, which may be chosen as the 'up' and 'down' eigenstates in Z direction, but equally well as the two distinct eigenstates of spin in the Y direction, or the again two distinct eigenstates of spin in any other direction. None is more fundamental than any other, so it is perfectly fine to consider 'up' and 'down' as superpositions of their Y direction counterparts |σ_y = +½⟩ and |σ_y = −½⟩ (curse the lack of formula rendering on this SE!).

What happens if you place several Stern–Gerlach apparati in series (and always use only one output beam as input to the next) is that the beam splits if the magnetic field directions are different (in proportions depending on the angle between them; for a straight angle the split is equal, whereas for a smaller angle there is a bias towards the spin closer to that of the input beam) whereas it doesn't split if the directions are the same. There is in particular no "memory" going back further than that, so if you split Z, Y, Z then 1/8 of the original beam will come out 'up' from the last Z and 1/8 will come out 'down', even though all electrons in those subbeams came out in (say) the 'up' subbeam from the first Z. The standard way of doing the math here is to say that when the beam gets to the Y splitter, the relevant basis to use is that of the Y direction spin eigenstates. The electrons coming in are all in the Z direction spin eigenstate of 'up', but since 'up' in the Y basis is an equal absolute value superposition of the two basis states, each electron will have an equal 50% probability of going into the +½ subbeam or the −½ subbeam, after which they will then be in either of those two spin states instead. Then coming to the last Z splitter, everything is the same but with Z and Y interchanged, so again each electron has an equal 50% chance of going into either subbeam. It's all very neat, but just not what a training in classical physics would have led you to expect.

In particular it has been seen as inconceivable that the electrons would *randomly* fall into one subbeam or the other, even though that is what the experiments suggest. The aim of the various "hidden variable" theories has often been to try and restore determinism by expanding the state of an electron to make it predetermined what it would do when subjected to e.g. a particular sequence of Stern–Gerlach experiments (1/8 of the original electrons being predetermined to go up–left–up when subject to a Z,Y,Z split, and another 1/8 being predetermined to go up–left–down in the same experiment, etc.), but those theories have failed to match experimental results (especially when entanglement and interferrence enters the picture, but that's another level of complications).

## More general reflections

Popular descriptions of QM often paint a picture where physical systems normally reside in one or another classical *pure* state, even though on microscopic scales you can temporarily create these weird quantum states that are superpositions of several pure states, but luckily those superpositions quickly "collapse" back to pure states, even though it is nondeterministic which pure state that will be the result. This picture is seriously flawed.

First, the "pure" states are not classical at all. The states one designates as pure are typically chosen to be easy to comprehend (to the extent that is possible), and one approach for such choices is to require that some observable (or quantity, in the classical terminology) has a distinct value; mathematically this means picking the eigenstates of that observable as the states to designate as pure (basis) states. But merely letting one observable have a definite value does not make the state classical — from the point of view of another observable, the state is typically a superposition of some other set of states where that second observable has definite values. A *classical* state would be one where both position and momentum of all particles have definite values, and such states simply do not exist.

Second, as mentioned above, what is "pure" or "superposition" is merely a matter of how we choose to describe the space of quantum states, not an aspect of the reality. Though that said, one should also be aware that some descriptions are more strained than others; there are states that would be labelled as superpositions in any humanly sensible description of the system.

Third, one should not make the mistake of believing that classical physics is always clear and intuitive whereas quantum mechanics is weird, because they both harbour plenty of things that are weird from the everyday layman perspective: shadows that are objectively less dark in the middle for one thing (by classical wave theory of light), or the finer points of celestial mechanics. But since the early writers on QM were classically trained physicists, they were biased in that these were *familiar* phenomena, not this new quantum weirdness. Even today the physics curriculum first deals with the classical material before addressing the quantum view, because the classical material is "easier". (Some parts surely are, but other parts I'm not so sure about; you can do a lot of QM with just linear algebra, whereas classical physics relies heavily on [PDEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_differential_equation).)

## Measurements

Another thing that frequently gets misrepresented is the matter of "measurements" in QM. From classical physics, we're used to the idea that *a measurement reveals what is already there*, a fact about the world that was true regardless of whether we knew it or not. Those in the business of actually making measurements know that it is not always quite that easy; a voltmeter has a large but finite impedance, so the mere act of connecting it to two points of an electrical circuit will slightly change the currents  and therefore also the voltages in that circuit, however in that case the distortion is typically small enough that it may be ignored. For measuring other quantities we may be less lucky, but for the sake of philosophy it is common to disregard practical aspects such as imperfections of measurement devices (among other things, because it makes the discussion much messier).

Either way, measurements in QM aren't that easy. A common *description* (which IMHO is misleading) of what is going on is that the observable again has a definite value (as in the above classical model), because that is true in the pure states, but since the state at hand unfortunately is a superposition this definite value degrades into a random variable. By "collapsing the wavefunction", the act of measuring forces this random variable to pick a definite value and thus reveal its underlying truth. This description is correct insofar as one can use it to carry out the calculations, but it is not so useful for philosophical enquiries. There is even a strong version of this description according to which the superposed state is unknowable, unlike the pure states which can be known, but that strong version is simply wrong and the spin example gives a good explanation of why.

If in the repeated Stern–Gerlach experiment we pick the 'left' subbeam coming out of the Y direction splitter, then the spin states of the electrons in that beam are simply 'left'; we *know* this, because we just measured this to be the case — there are no ifs or buts. For then *calculating* the effect of the subsequent Z direction splitter, the above description would ask us to instead view this 'left' state as the equivalent superposition of 'up' and 'down'; according to QM, this is just the same thing. By measuring the spin in the Z direction, we then force each electron to pick one of those two possibilities, or at least that is one way to interpret the calculations. A seemingly similar, but according to QM (and experiments) *incorrect*, probabilistic interpretation is that half the electrons going in are predetermined to become 'up' electrons and the other half predetermined to become 'down' electrons; that erroneous conclusion is however easy to reach if one believes "a measurement reveals what is already there".

A better picture of measurements in QM is that **a measurement of an observable of a quantum system is an interaction with that system which forces it into a state where said observable has a definite value**, subject to certain rules relating the probabilities of the possible outcomes to the amplitudes of the corresponding pure components in the pre-measurement state. This may sound strange, but it matches what many measurement processes actually do: to measure the vertical/horizontal polarisation of a photon, one aims it at a polarisation filter (of e.g. vertical polarisation), and if the photon gets through it has been measured to be polarised vertically, whereas if it is reflected it has been measured to have the complementary polarisation of horizontal. Even if the photon was in fact known to be polarised at a 45° angle before encountering the polarisation filter, it will be either vertical or horizontal when leaving it. Interactions between individual particles and pieces of macroscopic experimental apparatus have a definite tendency to behave in this manner; something as simple as having a particle pass through a particular hole constitutes a measurement of the fact that the particle was at the position of that hole, i.e., a measurement of its position. Measurements can be rather subtle.

On the other hand, it is *subjective* whether a measurement has in fact occurred, because **measurements happen when you extract classical information from a quantum system**; when describing an experiment, there is at least in principle always an option to delay the point at which the measurement takes place, by expanding what you regard to be the quantum system (to include more of the experimental apparatus, particularly detectors and registration)! Concretely, if your quantum state only includes the spins of the electrons, then the Stern–Gerlach apparatus performs a measurement of the spins by forcing each electron to go either into one subbeam or the other. However if you expand the quantum state to include the position of the electron, then the apparatus simply performs the reversible state transformations

```
|↑,0⟩ ⟼ |↑,+d⟩  (spin up at position 0 goes to spin up at position +d)
|↓,0⟩ ⟼ |↓,−d⟩  (spin down at position 0 goes to spin down at position −d)
```

What happens when the spin is instead |σ_y=−½⟩ = ( |↑⟩ − i|↓⟩ )/√2 (the imaginary unit i here is significant – without it we would instead have the state |σ_x=−½⟩) is that the transformation acts independently on the spin up and spin down terms, mapping

```
( |↑,0⟩ − i|↓,0⟩ )/√2  ⟼ ( |↑,+d⟩ − i|↓,−d⟩ )/√2
```

The electron coming out of the apparatus is thus in a state that is a superposition of 'spin up at position +d' and 'spin down at position −d', rather than in just one of the two. Because this is an entangled state, we now have the extra option of deducing the spin from measuring the position, but the Stern–Gerlach apparatus itself has *not* measured the spin. It would (at least in theory; I'm not versed well enough in the experimental  aspects to be sure of how practical it is to do with electrons) be quite possible to recombine the two beams using a second Stern–Gerlach appartus with the magnetic field in the opposite direction, and thereby recover the original state of the electron. The measurement does not happen until the electron hits a detector not part of the quantum system, and theoretically there is no problem of redefining that detector and its records as being part of an even larger quantum system, in which case the superposition persists until someone looks at those records to see what the detector registered.

## Final opinions

I believe the above is all established physics. What I haven't seen is anyone drawing the (IMHO) obvious conclusions of the above points with respect to more philosophical concepts such as determinism/nondeterminism, so the following rather counts more as my own opinions. It is however perfectly possible that this just happens to coincide with one of the standard interpretations of QM — a lot of them seem to have rather illogical names, so it is quite likely that I would fail to find this even if I spent a month looking for it.

There is a paradox present in the ordinary description of quantum mechanics, in that quantum systems are supposed to evolve [unitarily](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix) — a property stronger than deterministically in that not only is the future completely determined by the present, but the past is also so determined, since everything is reversible (no information is ever created or destroyed, just rearranged) — until a measurement occurs, at which point the system makes a random transition that creates new information (result of measurement) and destroys old (actual state before measurement). This is a paradox because the physics laboratories in which such measurements happen are built up from matter that supposedly interacts in ways that obey the unitary laws of quantum mechanics — if at the micro scale everything is unitary, then how can it fail to be so also at the macro scale?!?

One solution is apparent in the idea that *measurements happen when you extract classical information from a quantum system*. The catch is that in a quantum mechanical universe, there is no such thing as classical information, although at macroscopic scales you can get darn good approximations of it (or at least: so it seems). Consequently measurements cannot exist either (which resolves the paradox), although in interactions between micro and macro systems there has to be something which manages to produce *very good approximations* of them — maybe the superpositions do not in fact collapse, but rather one of the outcomes get heavily suppressed (somewhat like in [Grover's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover%27s_algorithm))? Or more likely, it's down to entanglement with the environment — certainly if you had a quantum system running the usual experiments to test whether the laws of quantum mechanics hold you would get an overwhelming probability for the conclusion 'yes', but low probabilities for any particular outcome in many intermediate stages which anyway aren't important. This is speculation, but speculation that could potentially be examined mathematically: would unitary interactions between macroscopic and microscopic quantum systems behave in ways that approximate the QM laws for "measurements" (for macro systems that approximate classical information processing)?

If they do, this also puts an interesting spin on the matter of QM randomness, since it philosophically comes out pretty much the same as the deterministic [pseudorandomness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_extractor) used for cryptography: both rely on external entropy sources (in the quantum case: entangling with the environment) to produce results that come out as effectively random. It's only that in the quantum case this happens spontaneously, whereas in classical computers we need fancy hash algorithms to achieve similar effects.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine for a moment that we sit down with a few friends to play a hand of poker. The cards get dealt, and in that moment before everyone picks up their hands we have a classical probabilistic situation. No one knows what their cards are; the best we can do is make an educated (probabilistic) guess about what kinds of cards we might get. Of course, the cards themselves are not probabilistic. Once the cards have been dealt, the hand we each have is *determined*. We just don't know what it is, so our knowledge is limited to probabilities. Incidentally, this is what card cheating leverages; people who cheat at cards do things that give them just a bit more knowledge about the actual state of the cards than the rest of us have — marking cards, dealing seconds, etc. — which makes their probabilistic assessments that much better.

Now, imagine that instead of using a normal (classical) deck of cards, I pull out my quantum deck and deal from that. In that moment before we pick up our hands we have the exact same probabilistic situation in terms of our *knowledge*, but the physical reality is different. Instead of having face-down hands of *determined* but *unknown* cards, the face-down cards have no explicit values. They are a 'superposition' of all the possible hands that could be dealt from that quantum deck. The moment I pick up my hand, the cards snap into focus as one particular hand, and every other card in the deck instantly re-evaluates its superposition to exclude the cards that appeared in my hand. In fact, this highlights the difference between classical and quantum probabilities. Once we've all picked up our cards, I don't know what's in your hand and you don't know what's in mine, but that's just lack-of-knowledge. Your cards and mine are both *concretized* (fixed in value), even though we both have to make probabilistic assessments of the other's hand. But the un-dealt cards that remain in the quantum deck are *still* in superposition, having no concrete value, and able to take any value except the ones that have already been concretized in player's hands.

What this underlying reality actually *is* is difficult to imagine; that's why there's so many different hypotheses about it. Generally I find it easier to think about this in terms of *systems* than objects. That's why I talked about a *quantum deck* rather than a set of *quantum cards*, because the individual cards have to be entangled with each other in the context of the deck for this to work (otherwise two of them might be observed to be the King of Spades). A system of this sort is (perhaps) like a big ball of tangled yarn: pull on one thread and the whole ball tightens or loosens or unravels. But analogies are all going to fail at some point, because the quantum world is fundamentally different than the classical world we are adapted to.

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice illustration for someone like me without the formal training. I know you can't really get it without the math, but you can get a kind of useful picture from imaginative descriptions like this.  Math is the power tool, but metaphor isn't shabby.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is related to Consciousness view of superposition.

H. D. Zeh, The Problem of Conscious Observation in Quantum Mechanical Description

The problems of formulating a process of observation within quantum theory arise because of quantum nonlocality (quantum correlations or \entanglement" as part of the generic state), which in turn may be derived as a consequence of the superposition principle. For dynamical reasons, this non-locality does not even approximately allow the physical state of a local system (such as the brain or parts thereof) to exist . Hence, no state of the mind can exist parallel" to it (that is, correspond to it one-to-one or determine it).

The problem does not only concern the philosophical issue of matter and mind. It has immediate bearing on quantum physics itself, as the state vector seems to suer the well known reaction upon observation: its \collapse". For this reason Schr¨odinger even argued that the wave function might not represent a physical state (neither of the system itself, nor of a system carrying information about it), but should rather have a fundamental psychic meaning".

A dynamical collapse of the wave function would require nonlinear and nonunitary terms in the Schr¨odinger equation . They may be extremely small, and thus become eective only through practically irreversible ampli-cation processes occurring during measurement-like events. The superposition principle would then be valid only in a linearized version of the theory perhaps related to wave function renormalization. While this suggestion may in principle explain quantum measurements, it would not be able to describe definite states of concsiousness unless the parallelism were articially restricted to quasi-classical variables in the brain. Since nonlinear terms in the Schr¨odinger equation must lead to observable deviations from conventional quantum theory, they should at present be disregarded for similar reasons as hidden variables. Any suggested violation of the superposition principle must be viewed with great suspicion because of the latter's great and general success. For example, even superpositions of dierent vacua have proven heuristic (that is, to possess predictive power) in quantum field theory.

The quantum world (described by a wave function) would correspond to one superposition of myriads of components representing classically different worlds. They are all dynamically coupled (hence \actual"), and they may in principle (re)combine as well as branch. It is not the quantum world that branches in this picture, but consciousness (or rather the state of its physical carrier), and with it the observed (apparent) world .

https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9908084

Comment: The idea that consciousness plays an essential role in quantum physics is a minority view that is only held by certain variants of the "Copenhagen Interpretation" of quantum physics, see the last paragraph of the ["Divergent Views" section of the Copenhagen Interpretation SEP article](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qm-copenhagen/#DivVie). The idea that superposition differs in some important sense from classical uncertainty is much more broadly accepted. Also note that environmental decoherence seemingly produces the same changes to the statistics as measurement by conscious beings.

Comment: Thank you. I have some trouble with your terminology here, but I'll try to follow up on this "consciousness" interpretation. It is true that a complete physical interpretation of "observation" was part of my curiosity. In this case, however, I was more interested in the  distinction between "superposition" and any state we call "probabilistic" or "future," with "observer" remaing constant.

Comment: See my comment on the original question. This is an example of the trend that I was talking about.

Answer (score 0):

What is important here, is that you have already specified a 'basis'. In this case, the two states of the cat being alive or dead form such a basis. In quantum mechanics, a measurement is determined by specifying a basis (ignoring so-called POVM's here). The possible measurement outcomes that can be obtained are exactly the states in the basis, and the probabilities are determined by how `close' your initial state is to each of the basis states.

But there is now something funny we can do, we can choose a different basis to measure in. Our basis has two states in it, both equal superpositions of the cat being alive and dead. However, one of them has a plus sign in front of the dead state, and the other one a minus.

Let us now measure with this basis. Assuming our initial state is the equal superposition between alive and dead with a plus sign, we will *always* get that outcome. But this is quite peculiar, we started off with a state that had some uncertainty attached to it, but by measuring in a different way, we will get deterministic outcomes. Compare this with the  classical scenario, where such a thing is not possible in a non-trivial way.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Schrodinger's Cat thought experiment is actually a confounding factor for your understanding.  Its meaning and purpose is not what most people think.  [As Schrödinger wrote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat#Thought_experiment):

> One can even set up quite ridiculous cases. A cat is penned up in a steel chamber ...

The point that this idea was 'ridiculous' has somehow been lost in the popular interpretation of the thought experiment and leads people to a simplistic and wrong idea about quantum mechanics (QM).  Essentially, it leads people to believe that a superposition of states is equivalent to not knowing the true state.

When I'm playing poker with my friends.  I don't know what cards are going to appear.  That knowledge is unknown to me until the cards are revealed.  There's nothing astounding or interesting about this.  It's definitely not something that required a large team of extremely brilliant scientists to figure out.

What is astounding about QM is that we can actually demonstrate in repeatable experiments that real objects are *actually* (i.e. in reality) in multiple mutually exclusive states at once.  If that sentence isn't strange to you, read it again.  It's absolutely self-contradictory but proven to be true.  Proven beyond a doubt.  That's what is so 'shocking' about QM.  It contradicts our experience of reality and the logic that we have built to understand it.

Comment: Can you provide references to such experiments? From my limited QM training, this just means that the system is a linear combination of its eigenvalues/eigenstates. It's nothing strange, just that the linear combination of eigenstates is also an eigenstate. And these eigenstates are just the wave function, which has a probabilistic interpretation. So it's not really in each of these states at once, it's in a state corresponding to a linear combination of eigenstates, which provide a complete basis for all possible states. Of course you could be talking about something totally different...

Comment: @user5728491 A wave function is a mathematical construct and nothing more.  It only exists in our minds.  You are essentially describing the Copenhagen interpretation that the waveform collapses (i.e. 'something happens') when observation occurs.  For examples look no further than the double-slit experiment.  Another option is to read about the various approaches to quantum computing in use.  Here's [an article](https://www.quantamagazine.org/frauchiger-renner-paradox-clarifies-where-our-views-of-reality-go-wrong-20181203/) about various interpretations of QM.